# Specific shuffling list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

So, I have a list of groups

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']]
```

and I need to shuffle a flattened version of this list

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

so that elements of the same group would end at some distance from each other. E. g.

`[a, c, b, d, f, e]` and not `[a, c, b, d, e, f]`, because `d` and `e` are in the same group.

I don't care if the distance is just one element or more, but any element *must* not be near another element from it's group. Is there any algorithm for this?

The algorithm also needs to tell if this cannot be done.

Comment: What happens when one group has more members than all the other groups combined?

Comment: what do you expect to happen if it cannot be done, for example: `[[a],[b,c,d,e,f]]`

Comment: This is Secret Santa shuffling list. And groups are people not interested in gifting to each other.

Comment: @moguzalp No, this is part of a tiny app for vkontakte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code makes a copy of your original list of groups and takes each time a random element from the (at each moment) largest remaining group. Not quite randomized, but should work for any case when there is no group with over the half of all elements.

```
import random

list_of_groups = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']]
l = [group[:] for group in list_of_groups] # make a copy
random.shuffle(l)
out = []
prev_i = -1
while any(a for a in l):
    new_i = max(((i,a) for i,a in enumerate(l) if i != prev_i), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))[0]
    out.append(l[new_i].pop(random.randint(0, len(l[new_i]) - 1)))
    prev_i = new_i

print out
```

Comment: The most probable distribution of groups would be like `[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], [g], [h], [j]]` I. e. a few pairs and a few singles, so i think `new_i = random.choice(max(((i,a) for i,a in enumerate(l) if a != prev_i), key=lambda x: len(x[1])))` would do it.

Comment: @Shark - no, you misunderstood that line. The `max()` returns the tuple `i,a` where `i` is the id of the group (0 … len-1) and `a` is the group. So I am taking the id with `[0]`. You cannot `random.choice` from that. Just use the whole code and it will work for your `[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], [g], [h], [j]]` too.

Comment: Now I see. I just need to shuffle `list_of_groups` before generating, so that algorithm choose random groups of the same length each time.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a mistype: not `a != prev_i` but `i != prev_i`

Comment: @Shark - typo fixed and list_of_groups shuffled, very good points! This will however not do much with your `a…j` example, because the pair-groups will be still put together apart from the singles.

Comment: Yeah, but any group could be last now, and `a` now has a chance to give gift to `j`. But if I add a group with 3 elements, it's members may not have a chance to give gift to a singles, but that scenario is, fortunately, rare in my case, so I think about it later.

Answer (score 2):

Let me take an approach different from the current answers

The Basic principle would be to [shuffle](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) every list within the list, [sort](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) it based on length, [zip_longest](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) based on variable arguments which is passed from the list and finally [chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the list and then unwrap it. Particular thing to note here how we can pass a list as a variable args to an iterator, which made life easier here :-)

Lets say your list is

```
yourList=[['a', 'b'],['c', 'd', 'e'],['f']]
```

My Work List (after copying to preserve the original list)

```
workList=yourList[::]
```

Shuffling every list within your list

```
[random.shuffle(x) for x in workList]
```

Next we sort the List based on length of each list

```
workList.sort(key=len,reverse=True)
```

and then finally chaining over the zipped shuffled list

```
[x for x in itertools.chain(*[x for x in itertools.izip_longest(*workList)]) if x]
```

And your Final List looks like

```
['e', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'a', 'd']
```

Comment: This is just like answer from @eumiro, but more elegant :)

Comment: I like your style, but it would be easier to copy & paste this when the comments between the code lines would be actual comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just a fast, not-very-elegant code:

```
example = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
result = []
block = None
last_block = None

while example:
    if block:
        last_block = block

    block = choice(example)

    if last_block:
        example.append(last_block)

    element = choice(block)
    result.append(element)

    block.remove(element)
    example.remove(block)
    example = [a for a in example if a]

print result
```

Although the problem which might happen is the case when there is only one block for choices. Like in this case:

[1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Of course there must be some sort of catching this exception, but for now I hope this code can give you some idea how to solve your problem.

- Edited due to an exception happening once in a while.
- Forgot not to use words like "list" as a variable name. Thanks for comment - not it's corrected

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give the "dumb", straightforward answer: just flatten the list, then repeatedly randomly shuffle it until you get an acceptable list.

This method has the property of being uniformly distributed amongst all legal lists, as well as being easy to prove correct and straightforward to code. It's only disadvantage is that it might turn out to be slow -- but given the use case mentioned in another comment, I believe it would be fast enough.

As for "is it possible" -- giving it a first glance, I think it should be possible if and only if no group has more than half of the elements, rounded up. If you consider the first and last elements adjacent, change "rounded up" to "rounded down".

Comment: I've thinked about it, but this is web app and it would be kinda pain in the ass for server to try many times for many users. And, given particularly unlucky group combinations, this could slow the app very much.

Comment: @Shark: You're right, it will (probably) be slower -- maybe even *much* slower -- but that doesn't actually mean it will be slow. I can't promise that this approach will be fast enough, but I *will* advise you not to fall into the trap of spending lots of effort and making sacrifices to try and speed up something before you actually know it even needs to be sped up. (I say "sacrifice" because all of the other posted solutions appear to be non-uniformly distributed, and I'm assuming a uniform distribution is actually desired)